# Adding Data to existing DataTable's DataRow

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

I want to add data to an already existing DataRow in a DataTable. 
The idea is, to do this without copying the data that already exists.

When writing some tests, I found out that directly inserting the data is much slower than copying both the existing data and the new to a new row and add that row.

*Or am I doing it wrong?*

First I create a DataTable with initial data.

Fill Initial Data:

```
DataTable table1 = new DataTable();
int count = 15;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    table1.Columns.Add("hallo" + i, i % 2 == 0 ? typeof(int) : typeof(string));
}
int newStartIndex = table1.Columns.Count;
DateTime pre = DateTime.Now;
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    DataRow row = table1.NewRow();
    for (int j = 0; j < table1.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        if (j % 2 == 0)
        {
            row[j] = 502;
        }
        else
        {
            row[j] = "test";
        }
    }
    table1.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Afterwards I add another 15 columns and the data.

```
for (int i = count; i < 2 * count; i++)
{
    table1.Columns.Add("hallo" + i, i % 2 == 0 ? typeof(int) : typeof(string));
}

foreach( DataRow row in table1.Rows)
{
    for (int j = newStartIndex; j < table1.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        if (j % 2 == 0)
        {
            row[j] = 502;
        }
        else
        {
            row[j] = "test";
        }
    }               
}
```

When taking the time, it shows that inserting the data (which should be exactly the same data as the data initially added) takes about 10 times as long as the initial filling.

Now I tried the same with copying the data:

```
List<object[]> toAdd = new List<object[]>();

foreach (DataRow row in table1.Rows)
{
    object[] newArray = new object[table1.Columns.Count];
    Array.Copy(row.ItemArray, newArray, count);             
    for (int j = newStartIndex; j < table1.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        if (j % 2 == 0)
        {
            newArray[j] = 502;
        }
        else
        {
            newArray[j] = "test";
        }
    }
    toAdd.Add(newArray);
}
table1.Rows.Clear();
foreach( var o in toAdd)
{
    table1.Rows.Add(o);
}
```

This takes about 2.5 times as long as the initial filling, which makes it a lot faster than directly inserting.

Somehow I think there must be a faster way to add data than to copy everything and add it anew.

I tried writing to DataRow.ItemArray, but the changes will not be present in the DataTable after writing there.

Any ideas? And maybe explanations for this behavior?

Comment: Not really to do with your question but you should probably wrap the datatable in a using statement

Comment: I need a longer lifetime of the object - thus I'm not using a using statement there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are going through such efforts, and probably have your own reasons.
Not exact syntax, however, have you looked into things like...

```
DataTable.Clone()  // to make a copy

DataTable.Merge()  // to merge one datatable all rows (w/Matching columns) into another

DataView oDV = YourDataTable.DefaultView
oDV.Filter = ...
DataTable newTable = oDV.ToTable()
```

Comment: Clone() and 
View->ToTable() would be making copies. I'd like to avoid that if possible.